# QCheckBox Indicator, SVG Image

Tags: qt, pyqt

Is it possible to prevent a QCheckBox indicator within a QGraphicsView from becoming pixelated when scaling the graphics view?

I have tried using a SVG image by setting the CheckBox's style sheet but that hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a QGraphicsWidget.  I believe the problem you are having is that Qt asks the widget to paint itself, and then scales whatever it painted - so I don't think that you're going to be able to use a QCheckBox and get the clean scaling that you're looking for.

There are a couple of options I can think of:

- Subclass [QGraphicsSvgItem](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicssvgitem.html) - This would give you the ability to use your SVG image, but you would have to essentially re-implement all of the QCheckBox functionality yourself in your new subclass.
- Subclass QGraphicsItem and create your own QGraphicsView-capable checkbox from scratch.  This would give you the ability to paint your checkbox however you'd like using the paint() function, but once again you'd still have to re-implement the QCheckBox functionality.

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do something like this. I will try using the QGraphicsSvgItem and re-implement some CheckBox functionality. Thank you.